# Split the categorical column into multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a toy data set generated by the following code:

`declare @tbl table (year int, month int, property  varchar(4), nights varchar(4), LOS int)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'VA', '1', 33)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'VA', '2', 43)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'VA', '3', 51)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'VA', '4', 27)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'VA', '5+', 82)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'PZ', '1', 37)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'PZ', '2', 63)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'PZ', '3', 41)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'PZ', '4', 67)
insert into @tbl (year, month, property, nights, LOS) VALUES (2017, 1, 'PZ', '5+', 52)`

[image]

I want to split on the column `property` into columns `property_VA` and `property_PZ`, which looks like the following:

[image]

Another question is that is that How can I append a new row called `total` to only get the sum of `LOS_VA` and `LOS_PZ`. I am not sure SQL can do this stuff

Comment: What have you tried? How is the result different from what you expected? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Show us what you've tried and we can help you figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: I understand that, I know how to do it in R, but I have no idea how to do it in SQL, I am looking for some `rbind` function similar in SQL. That is why I am here look for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use PIVOT, example

```
    SELECT  year ,
            month ,
            nights ,
            'VA' Property_VA ,
            VA LOS_VA,
            'PZ' Property_PZ ,
            PZ LOS_PZ
    FROM    ( SELECT    *
              FROM      @tbl
            ) TBL PIVOT ( SUM(LOS) FOR property IN ( VA, PZ ) ) PVT
```

Result

```
    year        month       nights Property_VA LOS_VA          Property_PZ LOS_PZ
    ----------- ----------- ------ ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
    2017        1           1      VA          33              PZ          37
    2017        1           2      VA          43              PZ          63
    2017        1           3      VA          51              PZ          41
    2017        1           4      VA          27              PZ          67
    2017        1           5+     VA          82              PZ          52

    (5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: or by just join and group by

Comment: @Von Thanks so much, I did not that we can do pivot table in SQL, which is very powerful.

Comment: @AkiraKaneshiro happy to help.

Comment: @VonAaron I have modified the your code a little bit to get the result what I want. `SELECT  year ,
            month ,
   property, 
            [1],
   [2],
   [3],
   [4],
   [5+]
   
    FROM    ( SELECT    *
              FROM      @tbl
            ) TBL PIVOT ( SUM(LOS) FOR nights IN ( [1],
   [2],
   [3],
   [4],
   [5+] ) ) PVT`
Actually I have another question, can I add a column called `total` to sum of all LOS for each property? I was thinking about to group by with CTE, then join with the pivot table. but it was not working for me.

Comment: @AkiraKaneshiro yes you can, just add up all nights columns..  example - 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Kcz-z_tUeYt28ppV7zo3Pa71xw--VfS

Comment: @VonAaron Gotcha, I was thinking too much :) Thank you so much